# how to transform numerical to categorical (binary) variable and why do nan values reappear after filling in with zeros?

Tags: pandas, nan, categorical-data

I need to create a categorical (binary) variable from an existing numerical variable that has missing values. After filling in with zeros, nan values re-appear. This is causing issues as later I would like to remove missing values for my other variables which I did not show in the dataframe. I do not want to remove any observations from the Write_Off variable.

```py
import pandas as pd
 
# create lists
df = [['F', 267], ['M', 230], ['F', ], ['M', ]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Gender', 'Write_Off'])
 
# print dataframe.
print(df)

# fill in missing values

df['Write_Off'].fillna(0)

print(df)

# check for missing values. the nan values are back for the Write_Off column!

df.isnull().sum()

# Create a dummy (integer) variable called y from the Write_Off column. Any value grater than 0 will take the value of 1. This means that there is a write-off amount. For values of zero there is no write-off amount.


df['y'] = (df.Write_Off > 0.).astype('int')

# print the dataframe. 

print(df)



# transform the y variable to categorical (binary) data. Is this the correct way to do it? y will be the dependent variable in a logistic regression.

df['y'] = pd.Categorical(df.y)

#check the data types

df.dtypes

# print the dataframe. the Write_Off column still shows nan values. 

print(df)
```

Please help me correct the code. Thanks.

Comment: You need to either reassign or fill in place

Comment: thanks, but can you explain please as I don't get it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, you almost did.

You forgot to assign the value to data parameter when creating dataframe.

Try this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df, columns = ['Gender', 'Write_Off'])
```

And everything will work.

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Comment: the only way to thank you at the moment is to say "thanks". it doesn't let me vote as I need a reputation of 15 to do that. I'll try to answer questions but please bear in mind I am just a beginner.